# Unable to see all management options in iis 6,iis 7

Tags: iis-7

I want to create an iis user and assign all permissions to it so that he can manage iis like admin.But i am not able to create a new iis user nor able to give permissions becoz the necessary options for these jobs like "IIS Manager Permissions","IIS Manager Users" etc are not present in my iis.I had checked all the options while installing iis on my machine.Still i am not able to see them.Am i missing something?Do i need to do some extra setting to enable these options? How to enable these options so that i can do my job?.Please help Me.

Answer (score 0):

IIS has no User Management options available. It's always controlled by Operating System. To be specific - by Local Users and Groups on Client OS like Windows 7 / 8 and Workgroup Servers or Active Directory Users and Groups in Active Directory Enabled Servers.

Comment: IIS Manager Users,IIS Manager Permissions ,Management Service etc..options comes under Management Category of IIS.I am asking about that.

Comment: It's available only on servers and in server connections. More information available at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742464.aspx